# Python : How do you mock a the result of a dependant function call and specify what it returns

Tags: python, mocking

I’m trying to mock the return value from a nested function call. This should be simple, but it’s not working.
So I have a Car class that has a poweredBy() member function that returns an instance of the Engine class.
The Engine class has a member getEngineType() that returns the string 'BigandFast'.

```
class Engine(object):
    def engineType(self):
        return 'BigandFast'

class Car(object):
     def poweredBy(self):
         return Engine()
```

so: Car().poweredBy().engineType() returns 'BigandFast'

I have a function getEngineType() that takes a car and returns the engine type:

```
def getEngineType(aCar):         
    return aCar.poweredBy().engineType()
```

I’d like to mock the getEngineType() function so I can change the result:

```
@mock.patch('testing.scratch.mock_test.Car')
def mockedCar(mockedCar):
 mockedCar.return_value.poweredBy.return_value.getEngineType.return_value = 'SmallAndSlow' 
 print getEngineType(mockedCar)
```

But this still returns 'BigandFast'. The line :

mockedCar.return_value.poweredBy.return_value.getEngineType.return_value  = 'SmallAndSlow'

does not have any impact on the mocked object that I can see in the debugger.
So my questions are:

1. How do you specify the return value of engineType() in the mock
2. How/Would the syntax be different if the Car was not passed into
   getEngineType() as a parameter but generated inside the function.

Comment: Shouldn't `mockedCar.return_value.poweredBy.return_value.getEngineType.return_value` be `mockedCar.return_value.poweredBy.return_value.engineType.return_value`?

Comment: Then the results of getEngineType is an "empty" Mock:   <MagicMock name='Car.poweredBy().engineType()' id='350511312'> not "SmallAndSlow"

Answer (score 0):

Since you start with a Car *class* mock and you set the `return_value` chain from there, you need to actually instantiate a Car:

```
import mock
class Engine(object):
    def engineType(self):
        return 'BigandFast'

class Car(object):
     def poweredBy(self):
         return Engine()

def getEngineType(aCar):
    return aCar.poweredBy().engineType()

@mock.patch('__main__.Car')
def mockedCar(mockedCar):
    mockedCar.return_value.poweredBy.return_value.engineType.return_value = 'SmallAndSlow'
    c = Car()
    print getEngineType(c)

mockedCar()
```

Output:

```
SmallAndSlow
```

So, you start with a Car class mock, then you get a return value of a Car object mock, then a poweredBy method mock, then an engineType method mock and finally the return value.

Unfortunately, I probably didn't use the right vocabulary here, but the gist is: `mockedCar` is a mock of the `Car` *class*, you need to instantiate it to access the `return_value` that you set.